# Permission Issue in Shopline CLI

Tags: themes

I am having an issue using Shopline CLI. I am uploading a theme to myshopline.com but it gives an error "You haven’t the permission to upload the theme package, please contact your account manager for help".

I am the store manager, I have created an account and also created an app and given permission as well, but still can upload theme.

Please let me know what could be the issue, didn't find any help on Google.

Thanks.